# VB script of finding page number

Tags: vbscript

The below vb script does not works perfectly with all the files to fetch their page number can anyone help me with this?

```
' By Chanh Ong
'File: pdfpagecount.vbs
' Purpose: count pages in pdf file in folder
Const OPEN_FILE_FOR_READING = 1

Set gFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set gShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
Set gNetwork = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

directory="."
set base=gFso.getFolder(directory)
call listPDFFile(base)

Function ReadAllTextFile(filespec)
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim f
Set f = gFso.OpenTextFile(filespec, ForReading)
ReadAllTextFile = f.ReadAll
End Function

function countPage(sString)
Dim regEx, Match, Matches, counter, sPattern
sPattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]" ' capture PDF page count
counter = 0

Set regEx = New RegExp ' Create a regular expression.
regEx.Pattern = sPattern ' Set pattern "^rem".
regEx.IgnoreCase = True ' Set case insensitivity.
regEx.Global = True ' Set global applicability.
set Matches = regEx.Execute(sString) ' Execute search.
For Each Match in Matches ' Iterate Matches collection.
counter = counter + 1
Next
if counter = 0 then
counter = 1
end if
countPage = counter
End Function

sub listPDFFile(grp)
Set pf = gFso.CreateTextFile("pagecount.txt", True)
for each file in grp.files
if (".pdf" = lcase(right(file,4))) then
larray = ReadAllTextFile(file)
pages = countPage(larray)

pf.WriteLine(file.name&","&pages)
end if
next
wscript.echo "Completed"
pf.Close
end sub
```

It works with some pdf file not with all, I am not sure but there is some issue with the regex here.

Comment: Did you look at the PDFs it doesn't work with to see if they contain a `/Type /Page` string?

Comment: I am not able to get you sorry. Can you please re-frame the question